# How to use JavaScript to detect iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**I have a html page want to make it viewed in two different ways:**

1- when viewed in iframe. (viewed full site html code).

2- when viewed without iframe. (viewed some of the code)

**I used This but there is not any thing appear in browser just the code but between head /head tag**

```
<script>
if(top!=self){ 
write.line('Site full html code ');
}else{
write.line('modified site html code');
</script>
```

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Read the error messages there.

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: write is not defined

Your code to detect the frame is fine. The error is in your code to write the content to the page.

There is no such thing as `write.line` in browser-side JS. You seem to have confused it for `document.write`.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the `window.parent` and `window.top` variables, meaning that if `window.parent != window` it is an iFrame.

Comment: This is actually top!=self, but you dont need window.self when it just returns the window

Comment: You misunderstood my point: You've rewritten code *which already works* while ignoring the code which actually causes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use something like this

var isIframe=((window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false);

Comment: In my case it is working without any issues even when it is embedded in another domains with different cross-origin. That's why I wrote Try it ;)

Comment: Ah, I forgot that `location` has some weird exceptions to the normal SOP rules. This still doesn't solve the problem though. Despite the question title, the code the OP already has to detect if the page is in a frame works fine. The error is in the code to output content to the page.

Comment: True that it doesn't solve his code but sometimes compact solutions are better for future maintenance.

Comment: So will you change your vote now or you still insist about the thumb down ;)

Comment: Compact? `top!=self` is considerably more compact than `window.location != window.parent.location`!

Comment: top variable may be defined in different locations and it may point to top variable or something else while window.location points to specific object not to a random object so that is why I choose it because it is more robust in all cases

Comment: You could use `window.top!=window.self` and still be more compact than your approach while having the same reduced risk of variable masking.

Comment: Maybe and maybe not having robust compact code is good for me. And my approach was better than the mentioned one at least before you add "window." to it which makes it a hybrid solution more robust and more xompact. ;)

Comment: "Maybe and maybe not" – No maybe about it. And it still doesn't solve the OP's problem.